# SQL Query to Find Matching Records but Excluding those that Match Second Criteria

Tags: sql

I have a SQL database and I want to locate all the records that match one criteria, but exclude from that set of results the records that match a second criteria.  More specifically -

Table 'Documents' with Fields = 'DocID',    'Description',    'SignID'

Table 'Signatures' with Fields = 'SignID',    'SignatoryName'

I want to find all the Documents that have been signed by a specific Signatory e.g.

```
SELECT d.DocID, s.SignID
FROM Documents AS d
INNER JOIN Signatures AS s ON d.SignID = s.SignID
WHERE s.SignatoryName = 'Search Name Here';
```

However, many documents are signed by more than one person (i.e. Documents > Signatures is One-to-Many).  I want to exclude those documents which have been signed by anyone else, other than the specific Signatory in the above query.  Or put another way, I want to find all those Documents that have ONLY been signed by the specific Signatory.

But I'm not sure how to revise my query to achieve this objective.

Comment: by using the above query, are you getting the multiple records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a try with below query:

```
(SELECT d.DocID, s.SignID
FROM Documents AS d)
temp1
INNER JOIN Signatures AS s ON d.SignID = s.SignID
WHERE s.SignatoryName = 'Search Name Here' and d.DOCID not in ( select DocID from temp1)
```

Comment: the AND . . . NOT IN . . . was what I was looking for.  Simply when you know how - ty

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that SignatoryName is not null, you could try:

```
SELECT d.DocID, s.SignID
FROM Documents AS d
WHERE 'Search Name Here' = (
  SELECT CASE WHEN MAX(SignatoryName) = MIN(SignatoryName) 
              THEN SignatoryName ELSE NULL END
  FROM Signatures AS s ON s.SignID = d.SignId
)
```